# Why does node.js render an array differently after I add more items to it?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Splicing the array in javascript in node console displays the outputs differently.

The sample output is shown below.

```
$ node
> a = [ 1, 3, 8, 5]
[ 1, 3, 8, 5 ]
> a.splice(2, 1, 4);
[ 8 ]
> a
[ 1, 3, 4, 5 ]
> a = [ 1, 3, 8, 5]
[ 1, 3, 8, 5 ]
> a.splice(2, 1, 4,6,7,8);
[ 8 ]
> a
[ 1,
  3,
  4,
  6,
  7,
  8,
  5 ]
```

i.e array

> [1,3,4,5]

is displayed horizontally. while the array

```
[ 1,
  3,
  4,
  6,
  7,
  8,
  5 ]
```

is displayed vertically . Why is the node displaying the array vertically ?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because it considers the output to be too long to be shown in one line - and does it a bit incorrectly.

That's how the key function looks in Node 0.10.31 (*current version* at the moment):

```
function reduceToSingleString(output, base, braces) {
  var numLinesEst = 0;
  var length = output.reduce(function(prev, cur) {
    numLinesEst++;
    if (cur.indexOf('\n') >= 0) numLinesEst++;
    return prev + cur.length + 1;
  }, 0);

  if (length > 60) {
    return braces[0] +
           (base === '' ? '' : base + '\n ') +
           ' ' +
           output.join(',\n  ') +
           ' ' +
           braces[1];
  }

  return braces[0] + base + ' ' + output.join(', ') + ' ' + braces[1];
}
```

[**Source**](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.10.31/lib/util.js#L412-L430). Don't ask me what <del>the heck</del> `numLinesEst` variable is doing here. The point is, when calculating the length of each element's representation, the function doesn't take into account all the 'color' metacharacters - and there's plenty of them. That's how the length becomes much greater than `'[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ]'`'s one. That's what you got now.

Now that's the same function in the most recent numbered release tag (0.11.13):

```
function reduceToSingleString(output, base, braces) {
  var length = output.reduce(function(prev, cur) {
    return prev + cur.replace(/\u001b\[\d\d?m/g, '').length + 1;
  }, 0);

  if (length > 60) {
    return braces[0] +
           (base === '' ? '' : base + '\n ') +
           ' ' +
           output.join(',\n  ') +
           ' ' +
           braces[1];
  }

  return braces[0] + base + ' ' + output.join(', ') + ' ' + braces[1];
}
```

[**Source**](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.11.13/lib/util.js#L488-L503). The difference is obvious - all the metacharacters are excluded when the string's length is calculated.

Now guess what: that `replace` op was introduced into the source code by [this commit](https://github.com/joyent/node/commit/1f5570471896b6723b723342d55ad50013ce3b82) from **March, 2013**, closing [this issue](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/5039).

And yes, because this issue is of very low priority, its fix is not yet in the *production*.